Oracle poorly performing SQL
I am working on a legacy system which uses Oracle database. Please don't ask me why data is stored the way it is :), there is a table ofsd_temp which has a varchar2 column entity_nums which has string of numbers separated by pipe delimiter
e.g.
|432124|
|12678|762333|74774|

There are about 300K records in ofsd_temp table, there is another table ofdl which has 150K records but the column is a number instead of string and below is SQL which is taking a very long time to execute returns about 130K rows. I can't change the way data is stored but if you have any suggestions to make it faster.
It is an insert-select combo, we have noticed sometimes it takes 7 minutes and sometimes 3-4 hours
insert into table
select *
from ofsd_temp sdtemp,
     ofdl dl
where '|' || dl.entity_num || '|' = sdtemp.entity_nums;


Are you really doing an equality predicate?  I would expect that you want to see if the dl.entity_num existed anywhere in the list (so that a value of 74774 would match the third row of your sample data) which would involve a like operator.

Hello, I will try it out and see if it is any better, I forgot to mention it is an insert-select,I will update the post

It's not a question of performing better, it's a question of what query you're actually executing.  If you really have an equality predicate, you could likely improve performance with a function-based index.  My guess, though, is that you don't have an equality, you have a like, and so the function-based index isn't an option.

dl.entity_num is a number so i would have to convert it to varchar2 before using like, i will try like to see if it is better

I'm not sure you understood Justin's point. They are talking about what is required, not what is better. You will simply have different results if you use = and like '%...%'. With dl.entity_num = 74774, you need to have only sdtemp.entity_nums = |74774|, or sdtemp.entity_nums = |12678|762333|74774| as well?

Are you allowed to create a materialized view? https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-MATERIALIZED-VIEW.html

@KlimentMerzlyakov only |74774|

My condolences to you. Your data format -- delimiter-separated items in single columns -- uses one of the most notorious query-performance antipatterns in the SQL world. I hope Larry Ellison sends you a case of fine  whiskey each Christmas.

You can't use an equality predicate for searching a delimited string. However, should you fix your logic to use LIKE or INSTR or some such string-searching function, Oracle will have to do a nested loops operation and scan the entire table for every driving row in ofdl, which very well could take many hours as you are experiencing. That's one of several big reasons why we don't violate first normal form and store a delimited string of values in a relational database.
The solution is to normalize the data, which you can do in SQL without having to create a new table or change the table structure. Simply do the transformation in-flight using a query block or CTE (named and reusable query block), so that you transform the delimited string into a set of discrete numbers. Then you can use an equality predicate in a join and Oracle can use a hash join. That will perform acceptably. Here's an example:
WITH ofdl AS (SELECT 762333 entity_num FROM dual) --dummy data,
     ofsd_temp AS (SELECT 1 myid,'|12678|762333|74774|' entity_nums FROM dual) --dummy data
SELECT /*+ parallel(8) */ *
  FROM (SELECT myid,
                TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(entity_nums,
                                 INSTR(entity_nums,'|',1,seq)+1,
                                 INSTR(entity_nums,'|',1,seq+1)-(INSTR(entity_nums,'|',1,seq)+1)) 
                          DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) entity_num
           FROM ofsd_temp,
                (SELECT LEVEL seq
                   FROM dual
                 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000)
         WHERE INSTR(ofsd_temp.entity_nums,'|',1,seq+1) > 0) sdtemp,
       ofdl dl
 WHERE dl.entity_num = sdtemp.entity_num

(the WITH ofdl, . . . ofsd_temp is just to generate dummy data, you wouldn't actually need those at all when hitting your tables). The query block labelled sdtemp is doing the transformation by combining a number generator (the CONNECT BY query block) with INSTR/SUBSTR to pivot your embedded values to separate rows. I used 1000 in the number generator to allow for up to 1000 numbers in the string, but it'll be faster if you lower that number to just above your actual maximum count. So, if you never have more than 10 numbers, make it 20. I also put a parallel hint in there (inappropriate for my test query but may help you with your real data) in case your database or table isn't configured to use PQ by default.
What this will do is permit a hash join, since hash joins require equijoins (the join predicate must be an =), which will make only a single pass on your two tables, making it by far the most efficient join method for your situation.
If you did ever need to isolate a tiny percentage of values, however, then nested loops from your generated/pivoted query block to an indexed ofdl table (you can't go the other way) will work, in which case the pivoting allows you to do a normal index seek, though in the opposite direction that you expected. To go from ofdl to ofsd_temp would indeed require physically restructuring the table in order to index each value.
So either way, whether hash joins or nested loops, getting this join to an equality (=) is your main objective. That's what normalizing your delimited string to separate rows will do for you.

One of the options could be to use a recursive cte to generate rows of numbers from your delimited string column (entity_nums). Within the recursion you can calculate the exact number of elements within the delimited string and create a row for each element within the string. Arguably, this should be faster than LEVEL with Connect By oversized number of elements.
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table ofsd_temp AS
Select '|432124|' as entity_nums From Dual Union All
Select '|12678|762333|74774|' From Dual;

Create Table ofdl AS
Select 762333 as entity_num From Dual

WITH    --  R e c u r s i v e    C T E : 
  nums ( entity_nums, rn, entity_num, lngth ) AS
    ( Select    entity_nums, 
                1 as rn, 
                SubStr( entity_nums, 
                        Instr( entity_nums, '|', 1, 1 ) + 1, 
                        Instr( entity_nums, '|', 1, 1 + 1) - ( Instr( entity_nums, '|', 1, 1 ) + 1 )
                      ) as entity_num,
               Length(entity_nums) - Length(Replace(entity_nums, '|', '')) - 1 as lngth
      From     ofsd_temp
     UNION ALL 
      Select   entity_nums, 
               rn + 1 as rn, 
               SubStr( entity_nums, 
                       Instr( entity_nums, '|', 1, rn + 1 ) + 1, 
                       Instr( entity_nums, '|', 1, rn + 2) - ( Instr( entity_nums, '|', 1, rn + 1 ) + 1 )
                     ) as entity_num,
               lngth
      From     nums
      Where    rn < lngth
    )

... the recursion resultset is:
/*
ENTITY_NUMS            RN  ENTITY_NUM   LNGTH
---------------------  --  -----------  -----
|432124|                1  432124           1
|12678|762333|74774|    1  12678            3
|12678|762333|74774|    2  762333           3
|12678|762333|74774|    3  74774            3      */

... now you can join it with your other table by entity_num columns
--    M a i n    S Q L : 
Select      n.entity_nums, lngth as total_nums, n.entity_num, rn as element_in_nums
From        nums n
Inner Join  ofdl o ON( o.entity_num = To_Number(n.entity_num) );

/*      R e s u l t : 
ENTITY_NUMS               TOTAL_NUMS  ENTITY_NUM  ELEMENT_IN_NUMS
------------------------  ----------  ----------  ---------------
|12678|762333|74774|               3      762333                2     */

See the fiddle here.
